# Find and Replace Words in a Directory of Text Files

Tags: programming-languages, replace

I am in the final stages of developing a mod for the Indie Game [Dwarf](http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/) [Fortress](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/07/24/magazine/the-brilliance-of-dwarf-fortress.html?_r=1&pagewanted=all). The last thing required before the mod is in working order is to go through and alter the Dwarf Fortress RAWs -- two dozen or so text files that contain information about the hundreds of creatures populating the game.

What this amounts to from a technical perspective, is going through a directory of text files, and basically performing a "Find and Replace" operation to alter each line.

Most of my programming experiences are with object oriented languages - C# and Java, and some experience with Assembler and C. However, none of these languages seem optimal for this kind of task.

The one catch in what would otherwise be a very simple substituion, is that because of the way the Dwarf Fortress RAWs are written, I won't know if I need to replace the line until further down the text file. Below is an abbreviated example scenario.

```
[CREATURE:WOLF]
    ...
    [Many irrelevant lines of tokens]
    ...
[BODY_DETAIL_PLAN:STANDARD_MATERIALS]
[BODY_DETAIL_PLAN:STANDARD_TISSUES]
    ...
    [Many more irrelevant lines of tokens]
    ...
[MULTIPLY_VALUE:2]
```

The program I wish to write needs to be able to read through to the [MULTIPLY_VALUE:X] line and then go back and replace the two lines containing [BODY_DETAIL_PLAN:Z] with [BODY_DETAIL_PLAN:Y], where Y changes depending on the read value of X.

I can guarantee two things:

- At *most* one [MULTIPLY_VALUE:X] line will appear between   [CREATURE:A] and [CREATURE:B] or [CREATURE:Z] and the end of the file.
- The [MULTIPLY_VALUE:X] line will always come *after* the [BODY_DETAIL_PLAN:Z] line, if it is present on that creature.

Based on the coding experience I have, the closest thing I have to a viable idea is writing a C program to read the file, using pointers to 'save' the location of the read lines and change them when the file reader detects the start of a new RAW.

*However*, that strikes me as inelegant, and runs into the trouble of me having no experience in implementing a find/replace function in C (or any language) in the first place.

Is there some easier way to accomplish this otherwise monotonous task of going through each text file by hand? I am totally willing to learn a new programming language, but I don't exactly know which language would be easiest to handle this situation.

Suggestions?

Comment: Seems like a perfect task for a scripting language like Perl, Python, or Ruby. Those languages do that sort of thing for breakfast. One question though..can there be a MULTIPLY line somewhere else in the file? I.e. do you require the intelligence to find it in the CREATURE segment, or could you just to a blind replace on any MULTIPLY line in the whole file?

Comment: @Casper - Yes, I thought a scripting language might work, but I have no experience with scripting languages, hence the question. The issue is that it's not the MULTIPLY line that needs to be replaced, but rather that the existence of the MULTIPLY line dictates what a separate line should be replaced *with*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..the reason I was asking the questions before is I wanted to know if the context of the lines to be replaced was important. Since if the context is NOT important then the whole recursive replace thing will be mostly a one-liner program.

Based on your answers I'm assuming that context needs to be taken into account. So with that here's a simplified example in Ruby. Just as an example so you can see how it works. The code is a bit verbose to help you understand it better. You could use it as a base and work from there.

The program works like this - let's say you have a data file `data.txt` like so:

```
[aaa]
[bbb]
[replace:a]
[replace:b]

[start_marker]
  [xxx]
  [replace:x]
  [replace:y]
  [yyy]
[end_marker]

[replace:c]
[replace:d]
[ccc]
[ddd]
```

You run the program:

```
ruby replace.rb data.txt
```

And you end up with `data.txt.bak` with the original data, and a replaced `data.txt` that looks like this:

```
[aaa]
[bbb]
[replace:a]
[replace:b]

[start_marker]
  [xxx]
  [replace:x was replaced!]
  [replace:y was replaced!]
  [yyy]
[end_marker]

[replace:c]
[replace:d]
[ccc]
[ddd]
```

The program `replace.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ftools'         # File.move
require 'extensions/io'  # File.writelines

file  = ARGV.shift
lines = File.open(file).readlines

replace_these  = Array.new
within_section = false

# Loop until we hit start_marker, then store potential
# lines until we hit end_marker, then fix the lines
lines.each { |line|
  within_section = true if line.match /\[start_marker\]/

  if line.match /\[end_marker\]/
    within_section = false

    replace_these.each { |line|
      # Do something clever...
      line.gsub!(/:(\w+)/, ':\1 was replaced!')
    }

    replace_these = Array.new
  end

  next if !within_section

  # Store lines to be replaced for later processing
  replace_these << line if line.match /\[replace:.*\]/
}

# Make a backup of the original file
File.move(file, "#{file}.bak")

# Overwrite the original with the new data
File.writelines(file, lines)
```

Ruby is a fun language to program in, and a nice addition to have in your "tool belt". So might be something you want to take a look at.

Comment: I am trying to run your example program, and am running into a problem with the `requires` you use at the beginning of the code. Both the `ftools` and `extensions/io` you use are giving me "no such file" exceptions when I try and run the program. Using Ruby 1.9.2p290 .

Comment: Ok. In 1.9 `ftools` has been replaced by `fileutils`, so use that. For `extensions` just install the gem: `gem install extensions` if you're using `rvm`, `sudo gem install extensions` otherwise.

Comment: I got the extensions installed, I think, but now I'm getting a new error: "uninitialized constant object::VERSION(name error)" I'm looking through to see if there's a typo somewhere in my 'require' statements.

Comment: I don't have Ruby on Rails installed, just Ruby - could that be causing the error?

Comment: @Raven - `extensions` might not be 1.9 compatible. See here (there's a patch): http://isitruby19.com/extensions . Another alternative is to install `facets`, which are 1.9 comp. Then require `facets/file` instead of `extensions/io`. Go with `facets` is my vote. That should fix it..

Answer (score 0):

use http://www.harddisksearch.com/ ..

Would be piece of cake.